# How to create a superuser in my own User Form?

Tags: django, authentication, django-forms

I am creating my own form to register users, but how can I make possible to create superusers in it, and also I know django allows you, call user in the views like this:`reques.user.username`. I can only use that using django forms or I can also use that with my forms

I creating my own form because I don´t want the restriccion django password have, is there a way to change that, in oder to not create my own form

Comment: `python manage.py createsuperuser` you can run command  and other way is that while saving User data make `is_superuser = True`.

Comment: okay thank you, Also you know a way to change the restriccions of django user form password, because i whant the password to accept numers or letters, but not a mix of that and the passsword leght can be of six characters not of 8 characters,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run command

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Other way is that while saving User data make

```
is_superuser = True
```

**For password**

you need to inherit from `AbstractBaseUser` and then override that password field and needed to update it's hash, don't know how you will manage that thing but different hash are available.

[Docs for custom user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project)